# Taking the year range of dominating years pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is as follows

| year | country |
| --- | --- |
| 1910 | Argentina |
| 1916 | Argentina |
| 1919 | Argentina |
| 1921 | Argentina |
| 1923 | Argentina |
| 1930 | Yugoslavia |
| 1950 | Yugoslavia |
| 1953 | Yugoslavia |
| 1961 | Yugoslavia |

My expected Output is>>

| country | period |
| --- | --- |
| Argentina | 1910 to 1923 |
| Yugoslavia | 1930 to 1961 |

Comment: The first thing you need to do is `group` by country. Please try that and report your findings.

Comment: It will give the country name and the count of its appearance in the column

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using all vectorized functions without `apply()` and `lambda`:**

You can group by `country` using [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) and then use [`first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) to get the first entry within group and use [`last()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) to get the last entry within group.  Convert the first and last entry to string using `astype(str)`.  Finally, reset index to bring the Pandas series back to a dataframe.

```
g = df.groupby('country')['year']
df_out = (g.first().astype(str) + ' to ' + g.last().astype(str)).reset_index(name='period')
```

(Thanks @mozway for suggesting to groupby() only once to further speed up the process :-)

Note that this answer uses all vectorized Pandas functions which is faster than the non-vectorized version using `apply()` and `lambda` functions which are slow.

**Result:**

```
      country        period
0   Argentina  1910 to 1923
1  Yugoslavia  1930 to 1961
```

If your `year` within a country is not sorted, you can also use [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.min.html) and [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html), as follows:

```
g = df.groupby('country')['year']
df_out = (g.min().astype(str) + ' to ' + g.max().astype(str)).reset_index(name='period')
```

### Edit

If you want to sort the number of years in the "period" column in descending order, you can use:

```
g = df.groupby('country')['year']
df_out = (g.min().astype(str) + ' to ' + g.max().astype(str)).reset_index(name='period')

df_out['num_year'] = (g.max() - g.min()).reset_index()['year']

df_out = df_out.sort_values('num_year', ascending=False)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

      country        period  num_year
1  Yugoslavia  1930 to 1961        31
0   Argentina  1910 to 1923        13
```

Comment: @NadunSamudhitha  Note that my answer is the only answer among all that use all vectorized Pandas function which is faster than the slow non-vectorized codes with `apply()` and lambda function.

Comment: what's difference between vectorized and non-vectorized code?

Comment: @PiotrŻak  Vectorized codes are those that use only built-in functions of Pandas that have been optimized to run faster.  They can also be interpreted as with  vectorization being the process of executing operations on entire arrays.   In contrast, `apply()` functions are just user defined function to run any codes.  As it is user-defined in apply with lambda function, Pandas cannot optimize it to run fast.

Comment: @PiotrŻak  The performance difference can be many times faster with vectorized codes, especially with large dataset which can be from more than 10x to more than 1000x times faster, depending on dataset size, of course

Comment: @NadunSamudhitha  To sort the number of years in descending order, see my edit above.

Comment: @SeaBean actually your argument of *vectorial is faster than apply* is not always true. For instance, on the provided sample, yours is a bit slower. You could make it faster by avoiding grouping twice on the first place by saving the groupby result ;)

Comment: Basically, `g = df.groupby('country')['year']` and then `g.first().astype(str) …`

Comment: @mozway  I tested for large dataset 10000x times the size of sample data, your codes takes 20.6ms, my original code takes 16.2ms and for enhanced code with grouping once, it takes 9.44ms.    Thus, even with groupby() tiwice, the vectorized version still run faster.  Of course, grouping once and with vectorized code run fastest.    Thanks for your advice  :-)    We all learn through answering.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` "country" and take the first and last element of all groups on the "year" column:

```
(df.sort_values(by='year')
   .groupby('country')
   .apply(lambda x: '%s to %s' % (x.iloc[0]['year'], x.iloc[-1]['year']))
).rename('period').to_frame()
```

output:

```
                  period
country                 
Argentina   1910 to 1923
Yugoslavia  1930 to 1961
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grouped = df.groupby('country')['year'].apply(", ".join).to_frame('period').reset_index()
grouped
```

transform list of strings to integer:

```
grouped['period'] = grouped['period'].replace(',', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: This also worked but it gave me all the years separated by commas.
Something like this>>
Argentina 1910, 1916, 1919, 1921, 1923, 1930, 1940, 1941...

Comment: Yes - i worked to sort that values and later get The first 4 charakters and 4 last with ‚to’ - but SeaBean provided more elegant solution.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to sort this df based on the number of years in the "period" column? Such that the team which has most number of years should come first and least at last?

Comment: That is one of option - sort entire dataframe by the longest period.

Comment: And also sort the list of integers in chronological order - [1,2,3,4]

Comment: there is also option of calculate difference (between the min and max value) - eg. - [1910, 1923] = 13 years

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.groupby("country")["year"].agg(["min", "max"]).apply(
    lambda x: f"{x['min']} to {x['max']}", axis=1
).rename("period").reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      country        period
0   Argentina  1910 to 1923
1  Yugoslavia  1930 to 1961
```